# Windows Server 2008 R2 Backup from Networked Drive

Tags: backup, windows-server-2008

Can someone give a solution similar to the old NT Backup that allows backing up networked drives on Windows Server 2008 R2?

I have one backup server running Windows Server 2008 R2 and 4 servers running Windows Server 2000 that have their drives mapped to the backup server.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to do a "pull" backup of the W2K servers from the W2K8 server. Why not do a "push" backup from the W2K servers to the W2K8 server?

Comment: Create a snapshot with VSS, and use robocopy?

Comment: joeqwerty: my boss doesn't want the process running on the W2K servers..

Comment: if process is local and dump vs a remote process that copy, the I/O is the same. Your boss goal are illogical.. as how would you restore the image ???? as a system state you must boot, and after apply the copy... you would apply a copy created by a win2008r2's version on a 2k ntbackup's tool ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I missed NTBackup in the recent Windows versions, too.  It was very flexible.

Have you tried [StrArc](http://www.ltr-data.se/files/strarc.zip)/StrArc64 by Olof Lagerkvist from [LTRData](http://www.ltr-data.se/opencode.html/)?  It uses the NT Backup API and performs practically the same kind of backup as NT Backup, but with more flexibility with its command line itnerface.  I just tested it, and it seems to have backed up Windows networked resources correctly.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with [Windows Server Backup](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee849849%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) that's built into 2008 R2?

Edit: I misread the question. I think you're doing it a little backwards. You should probably have an NTBackup script on each 2000 Server and have the drive to the backup box mapped on each server. You should dump the NTBackups from the 2000 servers to the 2008 box.

You couldn't have been getting system state and other important stuff doing it the other way around. Then you can use Windows Server Backup on the 2008 box to back itself up and the NTBackups from the other servers onto external media.

Comment: it won't let you backup networked drives

Comment: @Matt Updated my answer. I misunderstood what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Umm. What's wrong with [wbadmin](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc742083%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)?

Comment: Ah, I see - you don't want to back up **to** network shares, you want to back up the shares themselves... In this case, virtually any [third party](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_backup_software) will do.